# Show that $g_{ij}v^i = v_j$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I'm reading Frankel's *The Geometry of Physics*. On pg. xxxiv, he defines
$$
g_{ij} = \sum_k(\partial x^k/\partial u^i)(\partial x^k/\partial u_j)= \langle\partial\mathbf{p}/\partial u^i,\partial\mathbf{p}/\partial u^j\rangle = \langle\partial_i,\partial_j\rangle
$$
and claims that $\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\rangle = g_{ij}v^iw^j$. I didn't see how the product $\langle,\rangle$ is defined, so I assume that $\langle\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\rangle = v_jw^j$. Then, this should mean that $g_{ij}v^iw^j = v_jw^j$, or $g_{ij}v^i=v_j$, but if so, I'm having trouble proving it. One of my attempts went like this,

$$
\begin{split}
g_{ij}v^i &= \langle\partial_i,\partial_j\rangle(v^i)\\
&= \partial_{ik}\partial_j^k(v^i),
\end{split}
$$

but I can't make any conceptual sense out of it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define the term "metric." One way to think about it is that a metric $g$ (say on $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$) is an $n \times n$ matrix $g = (g_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ of real numbers; then you may associate to $g$ a pseudo-inner product $\langle-,-\rangle$ which associates to any pair $\mathbf{v}=(v^1,\dots,v^n), \mathbf{w} = (w^1,\dots,w^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of vectors, the scalar
$$
\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \rangle := \begin{pmatrix} v^1 & \cdots & v^n \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} g_{11} & \cdots & g_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ g_{n1} & \cdots & g_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} w^1 \\ \vdots \\ w^n \end{pmatrix},
$$
or more explicitly,
$$
\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \rangle := g_{ij}v^iw^j
$$
in summation notation. In this case, this equation is a *definition*, nothing to prove about it.
(Conversely you can define a metric to be such a product $\langle-,-\rangle$, at which point you can obtain the corresponding matrix $g$ by $g_{ij} := \langle \mathbf{e}_i,\mathbf{e}_j \rangle$ where $\mathbf{e}_1,\dots,\mathbf{e}_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$; the two viewpoints are equivalent.) Then we define the operation of *lowering indices*,
$$
v_j := g_{ij}v^i,
$$
which transforms vectors written contravariantly to vectors written covariantly. This allows us to write the product $\langle -,- \rangle$ using the more compact notation
$$
\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{w} \rangle = v_jw^j.
$$
Again there's nothing to prove here – this follows immediately from the definition of lowering indices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've talked with my professors and realized that my assumption that $\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle = v_jw^j$ was incorrect, since it ommitted basis vectors, and was also incorrect notationally since both are vectors. So actually $\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle = v^iw^j\langle\partial_i, \partial_j\rangle = g_{ij}v^iw^j$ now makes sense.